# Perl DateTime::Locale::en error

Tags: linux, perl, datetime, yum, rhel

I am trying to execute a perl script which uses [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Strptime/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm) on my RHEL5.8 work machine. Upon execution I  receive the error:

`Can't locate object method "am_pm_abbreviated" via package "DateTime::Locale::en" at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm line 777.`

I believe this means `DateTime::Format::Strptime` probably expects a newer version of DateTime::Locale than the one you have installed. I have tried to install using yum

`sudo yum -y install perl-DateTime-Locale`

This however conflicts with my vendor DateTime::Locale and I recieve the lengthy and repetitive error transaction

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/Base.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/aa.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/aa_ER_SAAHO.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/af.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/af_NA.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ak.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/am.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar_JO.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar_LB.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar_QA.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar_SA.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar_SY.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar_TN.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ar_YE.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/as.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/az.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/az_Cyrl.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/be.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/bg.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/bn.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/bo.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/bs.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/byn.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/ca.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/cch.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/cop.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/cs.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/cy.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/da.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/de.pm from install of perl-DateTime-Locale-0.45-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package perl-DateTime-0.41-1.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Locale/de_AT.pm from install of
```

How do I get around this?

EDIT

---

Output of yum repolist

```
repo id                                   repo name                                                                  status
elrepo                                    ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Repository - el5                        444
epel                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                              7,471
rpmforge                                  RHEL 5Client - RPMforge.net - dag                                          11,312
rpmfusion-free-updates                    RPM Fusion for EL 5 - Free - Updates                                          165
repolist: 19,392
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange. [DateTime version 0.41](https://metacpan.org/source/DROLSKY/DateTime-0.41/lib/DateTime) didn't contain any of the locale files that it's complaining about.

I wonder if this is one of those occasions when Red Hat think they know better than the CPAN authors and make brain-dead packaging decisions. It might be worth seeing if you can update DateTime first ("sudo yum update perl-DateTime").

If that doesn't work, then tell us which yum repositories you're using.

**Update:** Investigating further, I see that EPEL (which is the repo that supplies your copy of DateTime) has [a nasty DateTime bundle](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/SRPMS/repoview/perl-DateTime.html) which include DateTime, DateTime::Locale and DateTime::TimeZone. Which means you can't easily update one of them on its own. I hate it when they do that.

Not sure what the best approach is here. I think I'd build my own RPMs of those three modules and install them instead of the EPEL ones. But it might be easier to just install what you want directly from CPAN.

Comment: script is already up to date. Question edited showing repolist

Comment: You can get a healthy copy of DateTime from the DAG/rpmforge repository http://dag.wiee.rs/rpm/